# ProgressSlider not upating on MediaPlayerElement

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on a player based on XamlCustomMediaTransportControls sample. 
I need slider to be visible even when the controls are collapsed, and I simply made it a child of `RootGrid`

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomMediaTransportControls">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomMediaTransportControls">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
                    <Slider x:Name="ProgressSlider"
```

Problem is that as soon as the `ControlPanelFadeOut` VisualState is triggered, the `ProgressSlider` stops updating.
Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's by design. When control fade out then all timers will be stopped so nothing will be updated.

If you don’t want control will be fadeout and always visible on the screen, then set this RS3 API [ShowAndHideAutomatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediatransportcontrols) property to false.